# How do I disable anonymous access to S3 bucket in AWS account

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

I have store files in amazon S3 storage.Currently all users access the file path. But I want to restrict file path for anonymous users who should not open file path.also can not access using direct URL.

eg. http://www.test.com/test.doc  anonymous user can not access this link

So,How do I disable anonymous access to S3 bucket in AWS account

Comment: How have you configured your domain to access your bucket? Is it going direct to S3 or via Amazon CloudFront? Do you have static website sharing turned on for the bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I  have configure my drupal  site files with one of the module https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs   in direct s3 storage

Comment: How does your domain (eg `www.test.com/filename`) point to your bucket? Does the bucket have the same name as your domain? Did you configure a `CNAME` record to point to S3?

Comment: @john No.Bucket name is different than the domain name. I have not configure a "CNAME" record to point to S3. Sorry.but I m Working first time in AWS S3 storage.So, i have not much knowledge about it. i have configure with the help of this Source
http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/easy-amazon-s3-drupal-s3fs

Comment: Are you sure that users currently have anonymous access to the bucket? Can you provide a sample URL that they would use to access it? (You can change your bucket name, but keep the rest of the URL in-tact.)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein for your help . I solved my issue by creating with pre- signed URL

Answer (score 0):

By default, all content in Amazon S3 is private.

If you find that objects are publicly accessible, then things to check are:

- A **Bucket Policy** on the Bucket -- edit or remove it to remove access
- Individual Access Control Lists (**ACLs**) on the objects, probably added when the content was placed into S3. These can be reversed by copying the objects over themselves with a different ACL setting

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have given public access to your files. there are multiple way to restrict you file access. check the below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html